# How to Loop Subplots with Updated Outputs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, subplot

I want to create a frontend where the user can browse pictures forward by pressing Enter. 
Pseudo-Code

```
hFig=figure
nFrames=5;
k=1;
while k < nFrames
   u=signal(1*k,100*k,'data.wav'); % 100 length

   subplot(2,2,1);
   plot(u);

   subplot(2,2,2);
   plot(sin(u));

   subplot(2,2,3);
   plot(cos(u));

   subplot(2,2,4);
   plot(tan(u));

   % not necessary but for heading of overal figure
   fprintf('Press Enter for next slice\n');
   str=sprintf('Slice %d', k);
   mtit(hFig, str); 

   k=k+1;
   keyboard

end

function u=signal(a,b,file)
   [fs,smplrt]=audioread(file);
   u=fs(a:b,1);
end
```

where

- something is wrong in updating the data because pressing CMD+Enter increases `k` by one but does not update the data. Sometimes (rarely), the data is once the next iteration.
- something is wrong with while's condition because `k` can be bigger than nFrames. `keyboard` just keep asking for more inputs.

### My mistake earlier in Error-Checking

I had earlier a problem where the closure of the window lead to the crash of the application. I include this here because I mentioned a problem about it in the comment of one answer. I avoid the problem now by

```
hFig=figure;
n=5;
k=1;
while k<nFrames 

      % for the case, the user closes the window but starts new iteration
      if(not(ishandle(hFig)))
          hFig=figure;
      end

   ...

end
```

which creates a new Figure if the earlier was closed by the user. 
I tried unsuccessfully putting `hFig=figure;` inside the while loop's if clause earlier to avoid repetition in the code. 
Please, let me know if you know why you cannot have the handle `hFig` in the while loop's if clause.

---

How can you loop subplots with updated outputs in Matlab?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for functions you use. [`keyboard`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html) enters the debugger, the function is continued with F5 (by default). You're probably better off using something like [`pause`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html).

Comment: @excaza Not sure if it is F5. Now, I am in OS X where it should be FN+F5 or CMD+Enter but I am having a difficulty in detecting if the input was accepted.

Comment: The point of my comment is that you *don't* want to be in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the script waiting for an input from the user you should use [input](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) instead of `keyboard`.

Actually [keyboard](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html) makes your script entering in a `debug` mode. It stops the executino of the script as (like a `breakpoint`) allowing the user to, for example, check the value of a variable.

You can modify your scripr as follows (modification are at the end of your script, identified by "UPDATED SECTION):

```
hFig=figure
nFrames=5;
k=1;
while k < nFrames
   u=signal(1*k,100*k,'handel.wav'); % 100 length

   subplot(2,2,1);
   plot(u);

   subplot(2,2,2);
   plot(sin(u));

   subplot(2,2,3);
   plot(cos(u));

   subplot(2,2,4);
   plot(tan(u));

   % not necessary but for heading of overal figure
   %
   % UPDATED SECTION
   %
   % Use the string "Press Enter for next slice\n" as the prompt for the
   % call to "input"
   %
   % fprintf('Press Enter for next slice\n');
   % str=sprintf('Slice %f', k);
   % Use %d instead of "%f" to print integer data
   str=sprintf('Slice %d', k);
   mtit(hFig, str); 

   k=k+1;
   % Use "input" instead of "keyboard"
   % keyboard
   input('Press Enter for next slice\n')

end
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Can you output something immediately if correct input given? I have a difficulty that I feel that the software goes to some loop at some stages and I do not know if the input has been accepted.

Comment: I do not understand your question: do you want the user inserts a value for `k`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I had earlier a problem with the error checking. The closure of the window caused my application to be in infinite loop. I updated the body to show about how I fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, working technically. There may be better ways to do the error checking. I am always scared of repetition in my code, which I do there. Other error checks may also be necessary but I need to iterate now a few times to find them.